# Change row order on printing using Bootstrap 3.3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a project im using Bootstrap 3.3 to show and graph some data, on screen it shows perfect but I also need to print a report using boostrap printing classes

Is there a way to Switch positions between 2 blocks **ONLY WHEN PRINTING** the page?

[image: switch places]

Thanks for your Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use flex-box on an element containing both, you could use the `order` property inside of a print media query to change it:

```js
document.getElementById('simulate').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('container').classList.toggle('print');
});
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
   
#container > div {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px;
}

@media print {
   #container > div:first-child {
       order: 2;
   }
}

#container.print > div:first-child {
   order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>Top</div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
</div>

<button id="simulate">Simulate Print</button>
```